# htaccess Rewrite url dynamic length

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm starting on a website project where I want to rewrite urls with a dynamic length. For example, the following url's can exist in the site:

```
http://www.url.com/signup/
```

Or

```
http://www.url.com/profile/mark/pm/compose/
```

Now I've got a .htaccess script working, but I doubt it's efficiency. Here's the code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&subone=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&subone=$2

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?    page=$1&subone=$2&subtwo=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&subone=$2&subtwo=$3

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&subone=$2&subtwo=$3&subthree=$4
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&subone=$2&subtwo=$3&subthree=$4

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?arg[0]=$1&arg[1]=$2&arg[2]=$3&arg[3]=$4&arg[4]=$5
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?arg[0]=$1&arg[1]=$2&arg[2]=$3&arg[3]=$4&arg[4]=$5
```

I actually want to do something like this, but I can't figure out how I get it working...

```
RewriteRule ^{[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+}/$ index.php?urlvar={$#}
```

So the url

```
http://www.url.com/profile/mark/pm/compose/
```

Will result in

```
http://www.url.com/index.php?urlvar[0]=profile&urlvar[1]=mark&urlvar[2]=pm&urlvar[3]=compose
```

Anyone whow knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working:
In .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule (.*)/ index.php?path=$1
```

In index.php:

```
<?php
    print_r(explode("/", $_GET['path']));
?>
```

Comment: Thnx, but unfortunately this is not working..
When I run the url http://www.url.com/profile/mark/pm/compose/
A print_r($_GET) results in Array ( [path] => index.php )

Comment: You need a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php` above it or it loops.

Comment: Edited my answer. I managed to get that working on my system(: